# Deploying Rails to Amazon EC2 - We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-ec2, capistrano, runtime-error

I've been following the rails cast to deploy my application to amazon ec2 and I'm having some problems. It took me a while, but i got a test "blog" application deployed successfully yesterday using rubber and it's create_staging method. I am now trying to deploy my actual app but have run into some difficulties. The rubber command finishes, but when I try to access the website through the browser, I get the standard "We're sorry, but something went wrong error".

Look at the log files I hear you say, but when I log into the server through SSH as the ubuntu user and type `ls` nothing is returned - like there are no files on the server, when I know there are?

Any help really appreciated!

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
Started GET "/login" for 77.100.120.24 at 2013-02-11 07:28:18 -0500
Processing by AccessController#login as HTML
  Rendered access/login.html.erb within layouts/admin (17.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1082ms

ActionView::Template::Error (stylesheet.css isn't precompiled):
    4: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    5: <title>QLess - <%= @page_title || "Quick Drinks Ordering" %></title>
    6: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
    7: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "stylesheet", :media => "all" %>
    8: <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "large_screen", :media => "all" %>
    9: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    10: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  app/views/layouts/admin.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_admin_html_erb__2871469925121006882_32798020'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login to your server through ssh, then `cd` to application path and then run `cat log/production.log` or `tail -f log/production.log` if you're running app in production mode. Else use environment name instead of "production"

Upd: If you have other manifests or individual stylesheets and JavaScript files to include, you can add them to the precompile array:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin.js', 'admin.css', 'swfObject.js']
```

from here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

Comment: Hey Bob, thanks for your answer. When I log into the server as `ubuntu`, the home directory is empty - do you know where I might find the project dir?

Comment: Thanks so much! I've updated to include the log file snippet. Looks like something to do with pre-compiling assets? I have the rubyracer gem installed.

Comment: I really appreciate that update, thank you! I've added `config.assets.precompile += ['stylesheet.js', 'large_screen.css']` to `config/appliation.rb` now can I run `cap rubber:bootstrap` to apply the changes or will I have to `destroy_all` and then `create_staging` again?

Comment: Ahh... I ran `cap deploy`, now I'm getting a 503 error! http://ec2-50-17-16-200.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Ok after implementing your fix, I ran `cap rubber:destroy_all` and then `cap rubber:create_staging` then I had to ssh into the server, navigate to `../../mnt/project` and change the permissions to 777 as the project was made on Winodws but deployed on Linux. Thanks for your help!